# Verificar stock y añadir clases

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto "e-commerce" por así decirlo y tengo un "problema" que quiero solucionar.

Tengo un producto y su respectivo campo de "STOCK".
El admin ingresa al panel, agrega un producto y pone stock = si.

El "Si" y el "No" son agregados por el admin (o modificado)
En este caso, el Si / No es almacenado en la DB como varchar(2).

Y al ingresar en pagina producto:

Imprime stock (Si o No, según colocado en Base de datos).

Lo que quiero es que a ese Si o No, se le agregue una clase.

Si = verde

No = rojo

Lo que he pensado es agregar un "if".

```
 if (strpos($columnas['stock'], 'Yes') !== false) {
          (Agregar clase color green)
       }
 if (strpos($columnas['stock'], 'No') !== false) {
          (Agregar clase color green)
       }
```

¿Alguna respuesta?

EDIT: De ser la idea del IF correcta, utilizando strpos o strcmp, como se podria realizar el cambio de color verde/rojo segun si el resultado es Si o No?

Comment: ¿A que exactamente desea agregar la clase ? una fila de un table?

Comment: Quiero agregarle a un string el color rojo o verde, segun el resultado cuando imprimo <?php echo $columnas['stock']; ?> (Imprime Si o No segun la Base de datos) al imprimirlo quiero que sea verde para el Si o rojo para el No.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede utilizar la función [strcmp](http://php.net/strcmp) , tenga en cuenta que esta comparación considera mayúsculas y minúsculas. Sí retorna `0` son iguales .  Para las clases si usa `bootstrap` podría recurrir a su clase `label`  , caso contrario definiría en su `css` la clase y le agregara manualmente la propiedad `color: red` o `color:green` .

```
// la columna es igual a yes
if (strcmp($columnas['stock'], 'Yes') === 0) {
   echo "<label class='label label-success'>" .$columnas['stock'] ."</label>"
}
else{
  echo "<label class='label label-danger'>" .$columnas['stock'] ."</label>"
}
```

Sí desea que ignore mayúsculas y minúsculas.

```
if (strtolower($columnas['stock'])=== 'si') {
    echo "<label class='label label-success'>" .$columnas['stock'] ."</label>"
}
else{
    echo "<label class='label label-danger'>" .$columnas['stock'] ."</label>"
}
```

Comment: Lo que me estaria faltando a mi, es el codigo para agregarle la clase a dicho if / else.Si es que funciona tal cual se espera. <PD:  Estoy aprendiendo (no soy experto, entiendo pero no me sale automaticamente).

Comment: @jukxz actualicé mi respuesta. si tiene problemas comenta. Ojo con las clases de bootstrap caso contrario definirl en su css

Comment: Si estoy utilizando bootstrap. Pero de no usarlo, si o si se tendria que agregar manual? edit: acabo de ver el codigo actualizado.

Comment: Si en este caso, imprime el valor de "stock" a lo que quiero llegar es que verifique y añada la clase, y no imprima los valores.

Comment: @jukxz por eso le pregunté por un comentario a que desea darle el color. se añadirá al texto si o no me respondió.  ¿quiere imprimir el si o no ? ¿ A qué exactamente desea agregar la clase? ¿Donde está añadiendo esa validación? ¿un th? de una table ?

Comment: Se esta imprimiendo en un <p> dentro de un div con clase col-md-6. Quiero agregarle el color segun el echo ya realizado (si verde, no rojo).

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente, ahora lo que voy a hacer es reemplazar el strcmp por strcasecmp para el tema de mayusculas/minusculas.

Comment: @jukxz actualice mi respuesta. espero ayude. Saludos.