# Ingresar $valor a un campo y dependiendo el valor, modificar otro campo

Tags: php, mysqli

Poseo dos columnas:

> **stock** = string "si" o "no"

Y la otra columna con cantidad:

> **stock_c** = valor 0 a 100 (limite 100)

Uso **cotejamiento utf8_general_ci** y las columnas se encuentran en la tabla **productos**

Lo que quiero lograr es:

```
$stock_c = $_POST['cantidad']; // 0 a 100
mysqli_query($cnx, "UPDATE productos SET stock_c = $stock_c");

$query = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE productos.stock_c = $stock_c";
mysqli_query($cnx,$query);
// en este caso verificariamos si stock es = o mayor a 1.
if($stock_c => 1) {
 mysqli_query($cnx,"UPDATE productos SET stock='si' WHERE id_producto=$id_producto");
}
else {
 mysqli_query($cnx,"UPDATE productos SET stock='no' WHERE id_producto=$id_producto");
    }
// si lo es, actualiza stock = "Si" caso contrario ="No"
```

Seguramente algo este mal en el codigo, lo acabo de estructurar mientras pensaba la pregunta para poner como un supuesto ejemplo o "casi total" como guia para la solución.

---

**En resumen:**

Si `$stock_c = 0` | Actualizar o Ingresar en `$stock = "No";`

Si `$stock_c =>1`| Actualizar o Ingresar en `$stock = "Si";`

***Algo a agregar:***

El **usuario o cliente** va a tener un `<input>` numérico para la cantidad a agregar.

Aquí debería de tener un **limite** establecido según **$stock_c**

Y si `$stock_c = 0` desactivar el `<input>`

**Codigo que por el momento uso para reflejar $stock**

```
  <div class="stock"><p>Stock: 
        <?php
        if (strcasecmp($columnas['stock'], 'si') === 0) {
        echo '<span class="product-stock st-si">' .$columnas['stock'] ."</span>";
      }
      else{
      echo '<span class="product-stock st-no">' .$columnas['stock'] ."</span>";
      }
        ?></p> </div>
```

Este código lo obtuve al preguntar: [Verificar stock y añadir clases](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/132624/verificar-stock-y-a%C3%B1adir-clases)
Gracias a [@DevJoel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/12864/dev-joel).

Comment: Un pequeño error que veo, es que estas usando mal tu operador de comprobación (`=>`) fíjate en tu línea `if($stock_c => 1)` debería ser `if($stock_c >= 1)`. http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Si me guío por el titulo, pareciera que buscas hacer algún tipo de validación de 2 columnas, pero si leo el detalle de la pregunta pareciera que buscas establecer el valor de 2 columnas en base a un valor ingresado. ¿Cual seria exactamente la pregunta? PD: Si realmente estas haciendo esto `"UPDATE productos SET stock_c = $stock_c"`, le vas a establecer ese stock a TODOS los productos.

Comment: Creo que ninguna de las dos, lo que quiero hacer es que, al ingresar la cantidad de stock "numerica" ($stock_C) se establezca el campo $stock en SI o NO (dependiendo el valor, 1 a 100 = Si. 0=No)

Comment: ¿La variable `$id_producto` es un `int` o un `string`?

Comment: es un `int`, (autoincrement) establecido cuando se agrega el producto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar un solo `update` y establecer ambas columnas al mismo tiempo.
Así por ejemplo:

```
$id_producto = 1;
$stock_c = (int) $_POST['cantidad']; // 0 a 100
if ($stock_c < 0) { $stock_c = 0; }
else if ($stock_c > 100) { $stock_c = 100; }
$stock = $stock_c > 0 ? 'si' : 'no';

// Update
$sql = "UPDATE productos 
   SET stock_c = $stock_c,
       $stock = '$stock'
   WHERE id_producto = $id_producto";
mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);
```

Comment: Va por este camino, pero algo esta incorrecto, ya que si el valor es menor a 100, lo establece como 100. Pero no se busca eso, se busca que el valor ingresado sea el $stock_c y si ese valor $stock_c esta entre el 1 al 100, se guardara como $stock = "si" y si es = a 0, se guarda $stock ="no"

Comment: Hice la prueba modificando $stock_c = 50; y dio: `$stock = si;
$stock_c = 100;`

Comment: Dame un min, vuelvo a probar.

Comment: Buenisimo, funciono. Imprimio: `$stock = si; $stock_c = 50;`

Comment: funciono, Gracias, ahora vere de hacer una nueva pregunta con algo derivado de esta pregunta, para no generar muchas preguntas en una.

Comment: puedes verificar los "enlazados", agregue una nueva preg acerca de esto más avanzado.