# Establecer limite input numérico según $valor BD

Tags: php, mysqli

> Pregunta con código proveniente de: [Ingresar $valor a un campo y dependiendo el valor, modificar otro campo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/134278/ingresar-valor-a-un-campo-y-dependiendo-el-valor-modificar-otro-campo/134301#134301)

Gracias a [@Marcos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/16597/marcos)
Resolvi la anterior pregunta linkeada.

Ahora tengo:

```
     id_producto = 1;
     $stock_c = (int) $_POST['cantidad']; // 0 a 100
     if ($stock_c < 0) { $stock_c = 0; }
     else if ($stock_c > 100) { $stock_c = 100; }
     $stock = $stock_c > 0 ? 'si' : 'no';

 // Update
     $sql = "UPDATE productos 
     SET stock_c = $stock_c,
     $stock = '$stock'
     WHERE id_producto = $id_producto";
     mysqli_query($cnx, $sql);
```

Supongamos que el **cliente** quiere **comprar x cantidad*

```
<input type="number" name="cantidad" placeholder="¿Cuantos desea comprar?
```

> ¿Cómo establezco un limite al input de cantidad segun $stock_c?

**Si `$stock_c = 0` desactivar el input** (es decir, no hay stock)

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta  y  agregar el código que has intentado?

Comment: @Marcos espero haber editado bien y especificado mejor el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice [@Yo Albert](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/39181/yo-albert) lo solucione con `min` y `max` en el input.

Utilizando php:

```
<input type="number" min="<?php echo $stock_min ?>" max="<?php echo $stock_max ?>">
```

Como mi pregunta es de **PHP**, la solución que pense fue esta.

Para el tema de "desactivar el input" pense en hacer un `if`

```
if($stock==0){
  echo "No hay stock";
}else {
  echo '<input type="number" min="'.$stock_min.'" max="'.$stock_max.'">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Una idea es hacer lo siguiente;

Puedes agregarle los tributos `min` y `max` a tu input

```
  (entre 1 y 15): <input type="number" id="cantidad_Pendrives" name="cantidad_Pendrives" min="1" max="5">
```

El minimo y maximo pueden ser dinamicos dependiento de tu stock

ya con JavaScript puedes agregar el atirbuto `readonly` si el stock es 0.
Algo como;

```
var cantidad_maxima = $('#cantidad_Pendrives').attr('max');

if(cantidad_maxima === 0)
   $('#cantidad_Pendrives').prop('readonly');
```

es lo que se me ocurre.